# Select the parent class within same class names

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

If i use "nth-of-type(1)" selector, its select all of them. How can i select only parent div ?

Thanks

```
<div class="parent_div">
    <div class="parent_div"></div>
    <div class="parent_div"></div>
    <div class="parent_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using the same class name with different divs ? It has no sense

Comment: Im not. But a silly wordpress theme uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include directive parent container into your selector and use [direct child selector `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```css
.container > .parent_div:nth-of-type(1) {
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent_div">
      <div class="parent_div"></div>
      <div class="parent_div"></div>
      <div class="parent_div"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```